# How can I compare two JSON strings ignoring nulls in Java?

Tags: java, json, unit-testing

I want to be able to compare two JSON strings in my tests, but ignoring null fields.

Expected:

```
{ "field1":"value1"}
```

Actual and match:

```
{ "field1":"value1", "field2":null}
```

Actual and no match:

```
{ "field1":"value1", "field2":"non-null"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to get rid of null values and then compare.
google GSON by default ignores null values while serializing.

Jackson ObjectMapper also can do this with some additional settings.

The most straightforward (not necessarily the most proper) way to get rid of nulls in json would be the following:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = "{ \"field1\":\"value1\", \"field2\":null}";
String jsonStringWithoutNulls = gson.toJson(gson.fromJson(jsonString, JsonObject.class));
//results in {"field1":"value1"}
```